# preg_replace deletes rest of the line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I face an issue with preg_replace() that i dont understand:

Im trying to remove, from app level logs, passwords, tokens and other touchy datas. To achieve this, I'm using this:

```
$content = preg_replace(
        '/(?=\\\\"password\\\\")(.*)(?=\\\")(.*)/i', '\"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\",',
        $content
    );
```

It works perfectly fine with this string:

"{\n  \"username\": \"myuser@gmail.com\",\n
\"password\": \"1234password\",\n 
\"role\": \"ROLE_USER\",\n
}"

and regex builders like this one:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/

But when I use it in my app, it just output me this:

```
"{\n  \"username\": \"myuser@gmail.com\",\n  \"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\",
```

Instead of expected:

```
"{\n  \"username\": \"myuser@gmail.com\",\n  \"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\", \"role\": \"ROLE_USER\",\n }"
```

It removes the rest of the line AFTER the replacement part. I dont get why, I'm terrible with regex... 
How can I keep the rest of the line and why does it work on the regex builders and not in my app (PHP v7.0.15)  ?

EDIT: As I see upvotes on @Splash58 comments:
I cannot use array because I cant see in advance where is the value that needs to be obfuscated. It can be in $json['object1']['object2']['password'] or $json['objectX'][0]['password']. I dont want to search my array for keys to be removed in potentially hug arrays, perfs will be too bad. Is that more clear ?

Thanks for any tips !
Bor

Comment: json decode your string and do what you want with it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but no, dumped object can be very complex, so this approach doesnt fit. Its a security issue so i need something that works every time for sure.

Comment: I don't understand why using regex is better than  json_decode to get suitable array  - https://eval.in/934511

Comment: Because I nearly NEVER deal with simple one level array ?

Comment: Short answer, remove `(.*)` from your regex.

Comment: Nope.
Result: "{\n  \"username\": \"myuser@gmail.com\",\n  \"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\",\"password\": \"1234password\"\n}"

Comment: I  meant the last `.*`, also make the regex non greedy, it gives `(?=\\\\"password\\\\")(.*?)(?=\\\")`

Comment: Nope -_- :
"{\n  \"username\": \"myuser@gmail.com\",\n  \"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\",\"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\",\": \"1234password\"\n}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexes on such strings is not advisable, but your regex has some clear issues:

- It performs greedy `.` matches so that you risk to match quote pairs that don't belong together. It also explains the problem you mentioned -- that the rest of the string is removed.
- `(?=   )` is used in a wrong way: that represents a look-ahead *which does not actually grab* those characters, while in your use case it would be OK to actually grab them (which has better performance)
- For avoiding other mismatches it is best to also:

  - check for the presence of the colon and white space, as nothing else should appear between the key/value pair of the password property.
  - check that the string literal only has backslash escapes for non-quotes, as otherwise it represents the end of the string literal.

Here is the modified expression:

```
$content = preg_replace(
        '/(\\\\"password\\\\"\s*:\s*\\\\")((\\\\[^"]|[^\\\\])*)/i',
        '$1[OBFUSCATED]',
        $content
    );
```

Note that your input string is not JSON as true JSON would not allow literal backslashes to occur where you have them. For instance, it cannot have a literal `\n` where only white space is allowed. It seems like you escaped certain characters (newlines, quotes) where in JSON they should not be escaped like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very good explanation. It works and I can now mesure how much knowledge I lack on regex ><

Answer (score -1):

To address the underlying issue, you should ***never ever*** have sensitive data just floating around in your application like that.

***At the very least*** you should only have a Password Hash (ie. one generated by [`password_hash`](https://php.net/password-hash)) being passed around, but even then only for actually authenticating a user. Don't keep that stuff in memory any more than needed!

Once you've addressed the root problem, that is one of having unsecured sensitive data where it isn't needed, you'll find that you no longer need to "clean up" your application logs :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but imho, I disagree. My app is a Symfony2 API. I created KernelRequest and Response Listeners to be able to log input Bodies on POST requests and Output Content of HTTP responses (in my app's logs, which are ofc not publics). That is not "floating around in my application." And how can I log a user in without him typing his password ? At some point, I have to deal with clear password in memory to be able to log someone. Otherwise, how ?

Comment: Example for POST in logs:
[2018-01-13 13:47:14] [cf89980f] [127.0.0.1] [] app.INFO: ===> Incoming POST request on http://myapp.fr/app_dev.php/api/0.1.0/login_check with content :  "{\n  \"username\": \"myuser@gmail.com\",\n  \"password\": \"[OBFUSCATED]\"\n}" []
      Example for response (profile_picture obfuscated because it is base64ed):
[2018-01-13 13:47:16] [2fb8be2d] [127.0.0.1] [myuser@gmail.com] app.INFO: "{\"email\":\"myuser@gmail.com\",\"profile_picture\":\"[OBFUSCATED]\",\"push_notification_id\":\"MACHIN\",\"type\":\"public\"}" []